# The get View function in my custom adapter class is not returning any value

Tags: android

The data source which i am passing to constructor of custom adapter class contains correct value. here is the code for calling custom adapter,

```
CAforSearchResults ca = new CAforSearchResults(this, user, s1);

    lv.setAdapter(ca);
```

"user" contains correct value which i am passing to constructor.
here is my custom adapter class

```
public class CAforSearchResults extends ArrayAdapter {
Context ctx;
ArrayList<User_table> user;
SharedPreferences sf;
int userId;
public CAforSearchResults(Context ctx, ArrayList<User_table> user,
        ArrayList<String> s) {
    super(ctx, R.layout.searchresult, R.id.textView1, s);
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.user = user;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchresult, parent, false);
    }

    ImageView iv1 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final int p = position;
    if (position < user.size()) {
        iv1.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(user.get(position).getDp()));
        tv1.setText(user.get(position).getName());
        tv1.setClickable(true);
        tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }

    return row;
}
```

}

Now this list view lv is not showing the results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the list of elements to display to the super constructor. Here, your `ArrayList<String> s` is maybe empty...